# Changing Legend in ggplot & Linetype at certain point of x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've modelled 3 forecasts for total fertility rate, and I couldn't work out how to layer the plots, so I made a dataset of the values with the 3 different scenarios as a variable and then grouped values by scenario in my plot.

Here's my code for the plot:

```
ggplot(p4, aes(x=Year,y=TFR,colour=Scenario,group=Scenario)) + geom_line(size=.7) + 
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill= "white", colour= "white", size= 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
       panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid', colour = "gray"), panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, 
       linetype = 'solid', colour = "gray"))
```

And here's example data:

```
Year Scenario  TFR
2003    1   1.217396
2003    2   1.217396
2003    3   1.217396
2004    1   1.222510
2004    2   1.222510
2004    3   1.222510
```

and a `dput` of the above:

```
p4 <- structure(list(Year = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L
), Scenario = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), TFR = c(1.217396, 1.217396, 
1.217396, 1.22251, 1.22251, 1.22251)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The colour scheme ggplot used automatically is the blue fade one. I want the 3 lines to be 3 different colours.

Ideally, I'd also like to change the plot so that the linetype for all 3 lines changes from solid to dashed at the year 2019, to show that this is the forecast. Is there any way to do this? Something like an ifelse argument?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: the three lines in your example data frame are all the same line, so they are drawn over each other. You won't be able to see any differences between them because you will only see the final line that was drawn.

Comment: Also, you need to make `Scenario` a factor. At the moment, R sees it as a number and wants to give the colours a continuous scale.